# Issue with Code Sniffer on Ubuntu 16 - Install pfff

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpcs, phpmd

I am trying to setup PHPCS, PHPMD on my Ubuntu 16.04
I was following [these](https://www.ivankristianto.com/use-php-code-sniffer-phpcs-sublimetext-3/) instruction but I am getting stuck at Installing pfff

```
which phpcs
-/usr/bin/phpcs
which phpcbf
-/usr/bin/phpcbf
which php-cs-fixer
-/usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer
which phpmd
-/usr/bin/phpmd
which git #installed version is 2.16.1
-/usr/bin/git
```

Now when I do Installing pfff

```
cd /opt/
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/facebook/pfff.git
```

It gives me error

```
warning: unable to access '/home/<domain>/<username>/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
```

I also went to the .config folder but there is no git folder.
While ignoring the warning I foloowd the next step but it shows .configure file not found. Then I moved by ignoring all errors and started sublime and done phpcs setup

In sublime it gave me another error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/pfff/scheck'
```

any suggestions guys?